# OpenLayers 4: Load baselayer outside projection extent

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, extents

I have a map that uses [EPSG:3912](https://epsg.io/3912). Then I have base layer from CartoDB. When I zoom out I see: [image: map view]

My question is, if it's possible to have CartoDB layer loaded outside map extent (so that it fills white border) and with keeping projection as is?

Comment: I suppose your CartoDB layer CRS is EPSG:3857 and your view CRS is EPSG:3912. Set your view CRS to EPSG:3857 and you should be OK.

Comment: Transverse mercator projections will work reasonably well up to about 45 degrees either side of the central meridian.  You can set the projection extent as big as you need to display, or even leave it undefined (although that may result in some rough edges when zoomed out).  https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/abzEEGO

Comment: Yes I'm aware that changing view CRS to projection that supports bigger extent would solve that. But that would mean changing everything so it matches that projection.
My question was if it's possible to do that with some kind of workaround?

Comment: As @Mike wrote, you can use EPSG:3912 without specifying projection extent. If you don't veer far from Slovenia, it will work OK.